# Docker PHP Container Cannot Connect To MariaDB Container

Tags: php, docker, nginx, mariadb

I am using docker to start Nginx, PHP and mariaDB in seperate containers with these commands:

```
# DB
docker run  --name db -d -p 3306:3306 --restart=always -v /opt/db:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<pass> -e MYSQL_USER=dbuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=<pass> mariadb

# PHP
docker run --name php -p :9000 -d --restart=always --link=db:db -v /www:/data php:fpm

# WEB
docker run --name web -d -p 80:80 --link php --link=db:db -v /www:/data -v /opt/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf nginx:latest
```

(of course  has my password filled in) So far so good, have a spinning nginx running locally and I can see the index.htm and phpinfo.php in my www folder presented correctly at http://localhost

Next, I created a dbcheck.php page with the following contents:

```
<?php
$dbh = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'dbuser', '<pass>');
if (!$dbh) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully to MariaDB database';
mysqli_close($dbh);
?>
```

The result is that PHP does not have the MySQL extension installed.
What am I doing wrong and/or how can I install the MySQL extention (and where)

Answer (score 5):

Please use `db` for hostname instead of `localhost`. So, the code will be like this

```
$dbh = mysqli_connect('db', 'dbuser', '<pass>');
```

Because you link the php container with mariadb container using this options `--link=db:db`. It mean you link to `db` container and name it as `db`. So, php container just know `db` as the hostname for mariadb container

Comment: you're right, thanx.  However, is does not solve the problem. When I run the checkdb script, I got this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /data/dbcheck.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /data/dbcheck.php on line 2.  That seems to do with the PHP mysql or mariaDB extention not installed somewhere right?

Comment: If the error like that, you need to modify your own `Dockerfile`, then put command to install `mysqli` extension there