# Three container docker-composition : PHP can't connect to Maria DB

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mysqli, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'
services:
    php-apache:
        build:
            context: ./php-apache
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./DocumentRoot:/var/www/html
        links:
            - 'db'
        networks:
            - default

    db:
        image: mariadb:10.1
        volumes:
            - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql            

        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"            
        environment:
            TZ: "Europe/London"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpwd"
            MYSQL_USER: 'testuser'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'testpassword'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'testdb'
        networks:
            - default

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links: 
            - 'db'
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: 'testuser'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'testpassword'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'rootpwd'
            PMA_HOST: db
            PMA_PORT: 3306
```

This is based on a tutorial I found online.

When I run it, I can see that the PHP container is up. I can see that the db and php-mydmin are up. In fact I can successfully access the db from php-myadmin using the testuser / testpassword credentials.

But when I try to access the db from the main PHP application using

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","testuser",'testpassword','testdb');
```

I get

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 8
```

Is this a problem with the docker config? Can anyone see anything missing?

Comment: You're trying to connect to `localhost` which is the PHP container (I assume), where there is no database. Try connecting to the host `db`.

Comment: "No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 8" Whats on line 8? Also atleast provide PHP code for that file and related files.

Comment: Try to connect to '127.0.0.1' (loopback TCP) instead of 'localhost' (UNIX socket). I've seen this error when PHP configuration does not have the correct location of MySQL/MariaDB's socket file.

Comment: @BillKarwin It's in a different container and nothing provided suggests OP has shared the socket file between containers afaics?

Comment: Okay then I suppose PHP needs to connect to 'db' like the PMA_HOST does. I'm not practiced with docker-compose files. Definitely localhost won't work unless PHP and MariaDB are both in the same pod.

Comment: Yes @JonStirling that was it.

Obvious once it's pointed out. You wanna make that an answer I can accept?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker PHP Container Cannot Connect To MariaDB Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751239/docker-php-container-cannot-connect-to-mariadb-container)